# Segementation fault in a simple Quicksort program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, quicksort

When I try to execute the following code, it results in Segmentation error. Using online GDB the program simply stops working after the first call of partition function. The program never undergoes recursion and stops working right after `partition()` is invoked.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int partition(int arr[], int len)
{
    int pivot = len / 2;
    int left = 0;
    int right = len - 1;
    int temp;

    while (right != 0 || left !=0)
    {
        if (right != pivot)
        {
            if (arr[right] < arr[pivot])
            {
                temp = arr[right];
                arr[right] = arr[pivot];
                arr[pivot] = temp;
                pivot = right;
            }
            else right--;
        }
        
        else
        {
            if (arr[left] > arr[pivot])
            {
                temp = arr[left];
                arr[left] = arr[pivot];
                arr[pivot] = temp;
                pivot = left;
            }
            else left++;
        }


    }

    return pivot;
}


void quicksort(int arr[], int len)
{
    if (len > 1)
    {
        int pivot = partition(arr, len);
        quicksort(arr, pivot);
        quicksort(arr+pivot+1, len-pivot-1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,6,3,2,9,5,4,7,8};
    quicksort(arr, 9);

    for (int i =0; i< 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason when partition function is called the variables pivot, left, right are all initialized with garbage values.

Please Help.

Comment: I've not even run this and I'm already incredibly suspicious of `while (right != 0 || left !=0)`, especially since, if `left` is ever bumped by `else left++;` even *once*, it will cause an infinite condition on that while-loop. This *appears* like you're trying to implement Hoare's partition algorithm. I suggest you review how that algorithm works if that is the case.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. I meant to put right != pivot || left !=pivot. Its working now . Please put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Pretty sure you could also get away with `while (right > left)` , but your implementation is a little odd compared to classic Hoare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary `while` condition, `(right != 0 || left !=0)`, is flawed. All it takes is *one* lower-bound bump via `else left++'` and that condition will be perma-true, eventually leading to segment breach.

Rather, you want to collapse right and left until such time as they reach common ground. Ex: `while (right > left)`